# In Android, is there a way to reduce battery drain while using GPS?

Tags: android, gps, batterymanager

In our app, we are taking latitude and longitude every 5 seconds from the GPS to improve the location accuracy. In our app, we have to draw a line as per the user's movement. But we are facing the battery drain problem. Is there any way to reduce battery drain? Every time the location service shows that our app uses high battery. Please suggest some working solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [fused location provider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) for gathering accurate locations with lesser battery consumptions.

However, 5 seconds is too low a frequency if you wish to conserve battery. A person/ vehicle hardly covers a significant distance in 5 seconds. Try increasing the capture frequency to the maximum that will still suffice your solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot reduce battery drain. If you have an interval of 5 seconds, the GPS chip will stay fully functional.

Try to increase the interval to some minutes.